# A verb for accentuating an uncertainty

Tags: verbs, nouns

I need to express the idea that the act of adopting certain idealization produces the effect of increasing the uncertainty of a certain conclusion.

To say that that the idealization has an *uncertainty-fying* effect is wrong though. Alternatively, *uncertainty-increasing* effect is cumbersome. Any suggestions for an adequate term?

Thanks!

Comment: "the act of adopting a certain idealization **increases the uncertainty in** a particular conclusion."

Comment: You could say "obscuring", "muddying", "confusing", "perplexing", "equivocating", "endangering", "jeopardizing", "menacing", "risking", "discrediting".

Comment: Precipitating... should work?

Answer (score 1):

**Calls into question.**

> Warning: Broad definition of “cannabis” calls into question “hemp
>   exception” to new ISO cannabis exclusions...

[source](https://www.reedsmith.com/en/perspectives/2019/11/warning-broad-definition-of-cannabis-calls-into-question-hemp-exception)

In your example, the idealization *calls into question* the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks @Willk. My intention, however, is to indicate that the conclusion carries a certain inherent degree of uncertainty, but the act of imposing simplifications do increase the degree of uncertainty to a new higher level, and not that they call into question its validity. Does it make sense?

Comment: I don’t have an exact answer but you could employ the statistical concepts related to uncertainty. “This new constraint destabilize predictive models, increasing the underlying volatility in the set of possible outcomes.” “This plan will likely increase dispersion and variance of observed results.” Etc.